# How to remove "GivenStory Scenarios" section from Jbehave report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jbehave

Jbehave displayes "GivenStory Scenarios" section in Jbehave report, which i dnt need in Jbehave report.

How to remove "GivenStory Scenarios" from Jbehave Report.

Please see attched image. [Sample Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebxrA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that you're not at version 4.1.

One of the listed improvements on [this page](http://jbehave.org/reference/latest/release-notes.html) mentions that it no longer processes GivenStories if the the story-level has scenarios.  I'm not sure if this affects the report, but I would think it does.

Comment: Using Jbehave 4.1 version only. Still that column is displayed but i dnt need that as i dnt need to use "GivenStories" in my project . Any change i need to do it in Configuration so that will not get displayed?

Comment: Sorry, I spent some time researching the topic and probably found the same things that you did (very little).  The way I see it, you probably only have two options: Revert to a version of JBehave before GivenStories was an option or write your own reports/use a third-party product to do reports.  I've not done any research on the latter, so I have no suggestions on that either, sorry.